# What is this fruit (round, 3 cm diameter, yellow outside, 1 black seed, found on Easter Island)?

Tags: species-identification

What is this fruit (round, 3 cm diameter, yellow outside, 1 black seed, found on Easter Island)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some fruits may have more than one seed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at [Syzygium jambos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_jambos) in the [Myrtaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrtaceae).  The first link at Wikipedia has a number of pictures which are quite similar to your pictures.